# Error in Texmaker when trying to quick build any file

Tags: texmaker

Whenever I try to quick build a Latex file it gives the error shown in the image provided, how do I fix this?[image]

I am running Texmaker 4.5 on Windows 10

Comment: Have you installed MikTeX or TeX Live?

Comment: No, that's the only latex related software on my computer

Comment: Well, TeXmaker is just a specialised editor, not a LaTeX system. You should install one, preferably *before* TeXmaker.